# Execute the term $P=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $P:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^m$ is orthogonal linear transformation on some subspace $U$ of $\mathbb R^m$. Execute the term for matrix of linear transformation P using standard base. Explain the procedure.

I know matrix for orthogonal linear transformation is P=$A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$, I saw proof that this matrix is matrix of projection and it is orthogonal but,how I get that matrix, I could not find anything how to get that matrix, can you help me?

Comment: what do you mean by "execute" ?

Comment: I translate maybe it is wrong but how to get that formula

Comment: I don't know what your question is, but $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^t = AA^{-1} {A^T}^{-1}A^T=I$.

Comment: I need to show step by step how to get $A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$

Comment: How to get $A(A^T A)^{-1}A^T$ from what? What is $A$ anyway? What does it have to do with $P$?

Comment: I know that P can show like that and column of A is vectors of base